# Java - Using an object in a method that's instantiated in another method of the same class

Tags: java, class, object, methods, scope

I have a question about the scope of the object in Java.
For example, I have two classes called class A and class B. The main method is in class A and I instantiated an object of class B in the main(). I found that I can't use this object in another method in class A. Why is that? If I want to use a method in another class in a method of this class, how can I do that?

```
public class A 
{
    public static void method()
    {
     int i = example.value;
    } 
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
      B example = new B();
      method();
    }
}
public class B
{
 public int value = 3;
}
```

Can I do this instead?

```
public class A 
{
    static B example;
    public static void method()
    {
     int i = example.value;
    } 
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
      example = new B();
      method();
    }
}
public class B
{
 public int value = 3;
}
```

Comment: Scope doesn't apply to objects. It applies to names in the source code of a program.

Comment: Additionally, `i` is destroyed once `method` finishes execution, so you wouldn't be able to access it anyway.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis: So in my example above, how can I change to access the class B members in the method in class A?

Comment: Refresh your page. The linked post explains your options.

Comment: I don't understand that linked post. It has only one class. I have two different classes and want to use the object of anther class in the method of this class?

Comment: The classes don't matter. You want access to the object you've created in your `main` method and assigned to the `example` variable. You'll need to find a way to make it accessible. The accepted answer gives you way to do that.

Comment: So, if an object is instantiated in a method, it can't be used outside of that method just like declaring a variable in a method?

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the B object as a parameter to the method:

```
public void method(B example)
{
 int i = example.value;
} 
public static void main(String args[])
{
  B example = new B();
  method(example);
```

Comment: I edited above by declaring a static object outside of the method calls. Will that cause any problems? Thanks~

Comment: If you declare it outside the methods, but inside the same class, you won't need to pass it in the method parameters, but it should atill work. Google Java member variables.